# extract multiple words from a cell in excel sheet

Tags: excel, worksheet

My input is :

```
Col A                        col B
Java                     Looking for strong Java, J2EE, Spring, Hibernate, SQL person
J2EE        
XML     
Hibernate       
Spring
```

I want the output as :

```
Col C
Java, J2EE, Spring, Hibernate, SQL
```

How do I do it by  excel formula?

Answer (score 0):

Try the SUBSTITUTE function. It should what you are looking for:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/substitute-HP005209286.aspx